# How to have 2 QTreeview widgets side by side and resize

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I am using QTDesigner to design an application (I am trying my hand at a dual pane file manager). I can't figure out how to have the 2 widgets side by side so that they both resize when I resize the application

Comment: When asking, these help tons: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

A *layout*, as *JRazor* mentioned, is a good solution if you want your Tree Views to have *always same size*. If not, use a `QSplitter`

From the Qt documentation:

> A splitter lets the user control the size of child widgets by dragging
>   the boundary between them.

```
QSplitter *splitter = new QSplitter(parent);
QListView *listview = new QListView;
QTreeView *treeview = new QTreeView;
splitter->addWidget(listview);
splitter->addWidget(treeview);
```

**EDIT**

Sorry I didn't notice that you are actually looking for a *python* solution. I have provided a C++ example code, but I believe that it's not that big difference doing it with python.

Comment: I think the OP is actually asking how to do it in Qt Designer, rather than programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Use [layout](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/pyqt/pyqt_layout_management.htm):

```
layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
layout.addWidget(left_tree)
layout.addWidget(right_tree)
```

If you want use QtDesigner: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/designer-layouts.html

Comment: Use this code for logic file. The file in which you will determine the behavior of the interface and to assign the signals-slots.

Comment: @RobinSiebler. Yes it does. It's called "Horizontal Layout" in Qt Designer.